# Catch a loader error and try reloading

Tags: actionscript-3, loader

I am wondering if my code will work for catching a load error and if it is safe to attempt a reload. Since it is loading from my server I am assuming all files exist and the load error is just "something going wrong with networking".

```
m_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoaderComplete);
m_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, LoaderError);
m_loader.load(new URLRequest("MyFile.png"));

private function LoaderError(e:Event):void 
{
    //Try to reload
    m_loader.load(new URLRequest("MyFile.png"));
}
```

My two questions are as follows
1) Will IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR catch all of the possible networking errors that can happen when downloading a file.
2) Is it okay to just attempt another reload?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Yes it will catch most network errors, you might also want to check SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR but that probably will happen all the time if you don't have a proper crossdomain.xml file

2 - It is okay to attempt another reload but that might fail too, what I usually do is try to reload once and if that fails use a default image that I created in code. This way your program can still function even if it fails to load some images due to network problems.

Comment: Barış is correct in general, you should avoid looping for hopeless cases by checking the error and also have a retry limit.